# What does rc mean in ruby gems?

Tags: rubygems, package, versioning

I am reading bundler's [documentation](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html) and noticed the rc extension for a couple of gems versions mentioned in this document (like rails 3.0.0.rc). Does this have a special meaning? Does this apply for other gems besides the rails framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Release candidate, more on that can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Release_candidate)